# Is this the normal derivative of a measure? What does it mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, optimal-transport

I'm reading Filippo Santambrogio's Optimal transport for Applied Mathematicians and I've come across the following (on page 123). The context is that $\mathbf{v}_t$ is a vector-valued velocity function and $\varrho_t$ is a density measure.

> We say that a family of pairs of measures/vector fields $(\varrho_t, \mathbf{v}_t)$ with $\mathbf{v}_t \in L^1(\varrho_t; \mathbb{R}^d)$  and $\int_0^T ||\mathbf{v}_t||_{L^1(\varrho_t)} dt < +\infty$  solves the continuity equation
> $$ \partial_t \varrho_t \, + \, \nabla \cdot (\varrho_t\mathbf{v}_t) = 0 $$
> on $(0,T)$ in the distributional sense if, for any bounded and Lipschitz test function $\phi \in C_c^1((0,T)\times \overline{\Omega})$, we have
> $$ \int_0^T \int_\Omega (\partial_t\phi) d\varrho_tdt + \int_0^T \int_\Omega \nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf{v}_td\varrho_t dt = 0$$
> This formulation includes no-flux boundary conditions on $\delta \Omega$ for $\mathbf{v}_t$, i.e. $\varrho_t \mathbf{v}_t \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$

My question is this: what does the boundary condition at the end ($\varrho_t \mathbf{v}_t \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$) mean? It seems like we are multiplying a measure by a two vector fields. Does this give us a measure? Do we find the dot product of the vector fields first?

Answer (score 3):

The zero scalar product $\mathbf{v}_t \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$ would mean the velocity has no component normal to the boundary, so simply any flow at the boundary is precisely *along* the boundary, not *across* it.

With the density factor added, $\varrho_t \mathbf{v}_t \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$ means the effective transport of mass accross the boundary is zero. That means you *can* have a non-zero cross-border velocity at some point or area, but the density there has to be zero. Generally, even iv $\mathbf{v}_t$ is not parallel to the boundary the mass flux across the border is zero.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't completely clear, I'm not asking what the physical interpretation of this is, I'm merely asking how we multiply these objects (a measure and two vector fields)

Comment: @Tiocfaidh A density is a scalar, so it joins to either term, scaling is length: $(\varrho_t\cdot \mathbf{v}_t) \cdot \mathbf{n}$, or to a resulting scalar product, scaling the resulting number value: $\varrho_t \cdot(\mathbf{v}_t \cdot \mathbf{n})$.